# Retrieve from Cloud Firestore just document for One User and push into Widget Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

thanks to [Peter Haddad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7015400/peter-haddad)

We have built code to retrieve data from my cloud Store collection called "user"
at the moment as you can see into the widget we will show the use with a specific email "info@text.it"

```
class MainWelcome extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainWelcomeState createState() => _MainWelcomeState();
}

class _MainWelcomeState extends State<MainWelcome> {


  final databaseReference = Firestore.instance;

  Future<QuerySnapshot> getData() async {
    return await Firestore.instance.collection("user").where("email", isEqualTo: "info@text.it").getDocuments();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: getData(),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    Text(snapshot.data.documents[index].data["name"]),
                    Text(snapshot.data.documents[index].data["food"]),
                    Text(snapshot.data.documents[index].data["email"]),
                  ],
                );
              });
        } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none) {
          return Text("No data");
        }
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

where isEqualTo "info@text.it" I need to replace it with a variable to get into the widget each of the user subscribed into my form.
this is the form:

```
  void createRecord() async {
    await databaseReference.collection("user")
        .add({
      'name': '$name',
      'email': '$email',
      'password': '$password',
      'food': '$food',
      'image': '$image',
    }).then((value){
    print(value.documentID);
    });

Widget mailField() {
    return Center(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
        child: Container(
          width: 360,
          child: TextField(

            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
            onChanged: (value) {
              email = value;
            },
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              icon: new Icon(
                Icons.mail,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              hintText: 'La tua email',
              focusColor: Colors.white,
              hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              prefixStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              labelText: 'La tua email',
              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              contentPadding:
                  EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 20.0),
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
              ),
              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 1.0),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
              ),
              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 1.0),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

Widget submitButton() {
    return Container(
      child: SizedBox(
        width: 220,
        height: 40,
        child: RaisedButton(
          elevation: 5,
          onPressed: () async {
            setState(() {
              showProgress = true;
              createRecord();
            });
            try {
              final newuser = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                  email: email, password: password);
              if (newuser != null) {
                Navigator.push(context, PageTransition(
                  type: PageTransitionType.fade,
                  child: WelcomeScreen(),
                ));
                setState(() {
                  showProgress = false;
                });
              }
            } catch (e) {
              return Container(
                child: Text('Error'),
              );
            }
          },
          child: Text(
            'Registrati',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
          color: Colors.white,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black12, width: 1)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Firebase Authentication, then get the `email` from there:

```
  Future<QuerySnapshot> getData() async {
    var firebaseUser  =  await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    return await Firestore.instance.collection("user").where("email", isEqualTo: firebaseUser.email).getDocuments();
  }
```

Comment: I added a variable var firebaseUser; but it return: The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<QuerySnapshot>#ec13a):
The getter 'documents' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: documents

Comment: what does print(firebaseUser.email) give you?

Comment: can I ask please if I want to add static text here: Text(snapshot.data.documents[index].data["name"]),
how to do?
for example: Text ( "Welcome" ["name"] );

Comment: Text("Welcome ${snapshot.data.documents[index].data["name"]}");